# Failure of the maximum principle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, maximum-principle

> What are easy examples of some operators that don't satisfy the maximum principle?

For the double derivative operator $u\mapsto u''$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions on $L^2(0,1)$, we have $-u''\geq 0\Rightarrow u\geq 0$. Are there easy examples of differential operators for which the solution exists but maximum principle fails?

Comment: There are loads! Were you looking for anything specific?

Comment: @JackT Nothing specific. I want to see some basic examples. When I search I can only find that "second order operators with lower order terms" are a non-example but I want an explicit example which illustrates it. For example, if I take Neumann instead of Dirichlet boundary, then the solution doesn't exists because 0 is an eigenvalue. So that's not really a counter-example.